# TYPO3 fluid select property remains empty after submit

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

Im creating an edit page for my model where I have the following code:

```
<f:form action="createEditSave" addQueryString="1" method="POST" object="{activity}" objectName="activity">

<f:form.select property="competence" options="{competences}" prependOptionLabel="" prependOptionValue="" optionLabelField="name" />

</f:form>
```

When I submit the form(and select an option in the select) I expect the model in my createEditSaveAction to contain in this case a competence. But it remains empty even though the request does contain the argument. Am I wrong in thinking it should automatically select the object and must I handle it myself in my createEditSaveAction?

I believe my html is correct.
[image]

When submitting my form I receive no validation errors and get correctly send to my createEditSaveAction. Only here I expect my Activity model to have a competence model but the setCompetence() function receives a empty objectStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my own issue. The problem was the annotation in my model which said it was a objectStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what happened to send you back to the form:

- If the problem was validation errors the value should be prefilled since it will exist in the request data from the referring request, which is then read by the ViewHelper to determine the current value.
- If you redirected to an edit action the property value only exists on the object you passed and if that object is, for example, not assigned as a template variable in the action that displays your form.
- It may help if you specify the `optionValueField` property - and it may also help if you explicitly pass a `value` for the field.
- Don't forget that if your use case is somehow too specialised to fit this, you can always use `f:form.select.option` in a loop to render options manually, including selected attribute.

Final word: from the naming of your action it looks like you have one action that is capable of both creating and updating an object. This is bad practice - you should be using two different actions for this, and on the "new" action your object argument should be optional and null by default, on "edit" it should be mandatory. It may also be a good opportunity to review your controller in general, to confirm that it actually does use properly declared and annotated arguments and argument types for all the actions. If you circumvent the framework, things like form validation and subsequently resolving of field values may not work like you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response, indeed im using 1 action for creating and updating my object. Could you further clarify why this is bad practice? We used it for saving time for creating another view.

Comment: optionValueField makes no difference since I think by default is uses uid which should be good. And im not receiving validation errors or I wont get in my createEditSaveAction

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with my form, I had to include both the name *and* the propery tag.

```
<f:form.select name="foo" property="foo">
    <f:form.select.option value="bar">Bar</f:form.select.option>
</f:form.select>
```